# TeXstudio - Biber keeps running on "Build & View" multiple times

Tags: biblatex, texstudio, biber

If I run "Build & View" on TeXstudio, it starts running Biber about 5-7 times. Additionally, it builds up the bibliography wrong, while it enumerates every cite with number 0. It worked fine before. I think it happend after I clicked "Clean Auxiliary Files..". Now it drives me really crazy. Not only because the bibliography is not building it the proper way, but building the pdf takes so much time, cuz biber running multiple times.

This is in my .tex configuration:

```
\usepackage[style=numeric,backend=biber,sorting=none,defernumbers=true]{biblatex}
```

This is the message I get after building the pdf:

```
Process started: "/usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/x86_64-darwin/biber" "masterthesis"

INFO - This is Biber 2.1
INFO - Logfile is 'masterthesis.blg'
INFO - Reading 'masterthesis.bcf'
INFO - Found 7 citekeys in bib section 0
INFO - Processing section 0
INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'masterthesis.bib' for section 0
INFO - Decoding LaTeX character macros into UTF-8
INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'masterthesis.bib'
INFO - Overriding locale 'de-DE' defaults 'normalization = NFD' with 'normalization = prenormalized'
INFO - Overriding locale 'de-DE' defaults 'variable = shifted' with 'variable = non-ignorable'
INFO - Sorting list 'none' of type 'entry' with scheme 'none' and locale 'de-DE'
INFO - No sort tailoring available for locale 'de-DE'
INFO - Writing 'masterthesis.bbl' with encoding 'UTF-8'
INFO - Output to masterthesis.bbl
INFO - WARNINGS: 0

Process exited normally

Process started: /Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "masterthesis".tex

Process exited normally
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know Biber needs an extra run, but I think it is not usual that after a build and view is applied up to 7 times. Furthermore it is not even building the bibliography the right way.

Comment: Your biber is quite old,  and so probably also biblatex. Perhaps there is bug that confuse texstudio. Try to compile manually and check the log-files.

Comment: Can you reproduce this behaviour in a minimal example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864))? Can you show us such a file? Normally, it should be enough to run Biber once, sometimes twice is necessary. Can you show us the settings of your editor?

Comment: I found the issue. It was my fault. I separated multiple author in the bib file with a "comma" instead with a "and". Sorry I just deleted the line in my post, thought it would be irrelevant. :I

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was about a problem in the OP's `.bib` file that could not be diagnosed from the information given in the question. The OP sorted it out themselves eventually.